# Problem installing a module

Tags: 7

When I try to enable a module I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function modulename_cron() in /home/modulename.install on line 17
```

In modulename.install I have

```
function modulename_install() {
  db_query('ALTER TABLE {node_revisions} ENGINE = MYISAM');
  db_query('ALTER TABLE {node_revisions} ADD FULLTEXT `similar` (`title`, `body`)');
  modulename_cron();
}
```

module_cron() is definitely defined in my modulename.module file. What could cause this problem and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for hook_install](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_install/6). It says:

> Note that functions declared in the module being installed are not yet available. The implementation of hook_install() will need to explicitly load the module before any declared functions may be invoked.